# How can I deserialize a DBTransaction object gained via API call?

Tags: transactions, deserialization, webapi

I have a business logic (logic) WebAPI project calling our Data Access Layer (DAL) WebAPI project, which uses Dapper.

We've had success with most things so far, but I'm now trying to execute a multi-step AddStaffUser function, and I want to wrap the whole thing in a DBTransaction.

I have an API call in the logic project:

`response = ApiClient.PostAsync("DAL/Common/BeginTransaction", null).Result;`

On the DAL side:

```
        public static void ConfigureCommonApi(this WebApplication app) {
            app.MapPost($"DAL/Common/BeginTransaction", BeginTransaction);
        }

        private static async Task<IDbTransaction> BeginTransaction(CommonData data) {
            try {
                var txn = await data.BeginTransaction("CRM");
                return txn;
            } catch {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

```
    public async Task<IDbTransaction> BeginTransaction(string connectionId = "Default") {
        IDbConnection cn = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString(connectionId));
        cn.Open();
        var transaction = cn.BeginTransaction();
        return transaction;
    }
```

which returns the DBTransaction object, but I can't deserialize it.

I have tried the following:

```
var txn = response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<IDbTransaction>().Result;
```

but I get an error saying I can't deserialize to an interface.  So, I tried:

```
var txn = response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<DbTransaction>().Result;
```

which results in:

```
System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=One or more errors occurred. (Deserialization of types without a parameterless constructor, a singular parameterized constructor, or a parameterized constructor annotated with 'JsonConstructorAttribute' is not supported. Type 'System.Data.Common.DbTransaction'. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.)
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at CRM.API.APIs.Administration.<CreateStaffUserAsync>d__32.MoveNext() in D:\Dev\CRM.API\APIs\Administration.cs:line 622

Inner Exception 1:
NotSupportedException: Deserialization of types without a parameterless constructor, a singular parameterized constructor, or a parameterized constructor annotated with 'JsonConstructorAttribute' is not supported. Type 'System.Data.Common.DbTransaction'. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.

Inner Exception 2:
NotSupportedException: Deserialization of types without a parameterless constructor, a singular parameterized constructor, or a parameterized constructor annotated with 'JsonConstructorAttribute' is not supported. Type 'System.Data.Common.DbTransaction'.
```

I then tried:

```
var dyn = response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<dynamic>().Result;
var txn = (DBTransaction)dyn;
```

and got:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Cannot convert type 'System.Text.Json.JsonElement' to 'System.Data.Common.DbTransaction'
  Source=System.Linq.Expressions
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    CRM.API.APIs.Administration.CreateStaffUserAsync(DataModels.Administration.NewStaffUserModel) in Administration.cs
```

I've tried reading quite a few responses here on SO, but nothing seems to be working.  I'm new to WebAPI and Blazor in general, so be gentle, and thanks.  :)